# Calling child class constructor before parent constructor

Tags: c#

Is it possible to call the constructor of child class before the constructor of the parent class?

Someone said it is indeed possible with the use of a virtual method, but I can't find a way to do so.

Answer (score 8):

In IL, this is possible. In C#: no.

You *can* use `virtual` to run *a* method in a type before that type's ctor, but it is discouraged and risky. But:

```
class Foo {
    public Foo() {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo ctor");
        SomeMethod(); // BAD IDEA (calling a virtual method in a ctor)
    }
    protected virtual void SomeMethod() {}
}
class Bar : Foo {
    protected override void SomeMethod() {
        Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod in Bar");
    }
    public Bar() : base() { /* only to show call order */
        Console.WriteLine("Bar ctor");
    }
}
```

It is a bad idea because you can't guarantee that the subclasses are *ready* for the method-call.